# How do I do a BCD to unsigned integer conversion in vhdl or Labview

Tags: vhdl, labview, bcd

I am programming an application in vhdl for a National Instruments CompactRio. One of the inputs is from a scale that only outputs an ASCII string of the weight on the scale. I know I can convert the ASCII digits to Binary Coded Decimal simply by removing the 4 MSBs, but how do I convert that do an unsigned integer using vhdl?  What is the fastest algorithm for values that range from 0 to 9999?

Comment: By "fastest", do you mean "lowest footprint"?

Comment: Fastest to develop?  I'm sure NI has a string to integer block...

Comment: After re-reading your question it's not clear to me if you want LabVIEW code or VHDL code?

Comment: fastest as in least clock cycles to complete while running. Labview does not appear to have a string to integer conversion when targeting the CompactRio FPGA platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry looked into [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) and realised it's not an ASCII representation of a numeric.
I would convert the string into an U8 (using [String To Byte Array](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361G-01/glang/string_to_byte_array/)), and feed that into a for-loop and multiply that with a constant array, this array would  be [1000, 100, 10, 1], and summate all the elements of the resulting product, that should give you the numeric data of the string.